# Drupal Form API tableselect programmatically check or uncheck checkbox

Tags: 7, forms

I followed [this](http://drupal.org/node/945102) code example and built up my own version of how I want to use the tableselect. I want to use the table select for configurations. To do this I need programmatically check or uncheck a checkbox. How would I go about doing this.

Here is the general idea of my code

```
function my_form($form, $form_state) {
  $users = array(
    array('uid' => 1, 'first_name' => 'Indy', 'last_name' => 'Jones'),
    array('uid' => 2, 'first_name' => 'Darth', 'last_name' => 'Vader'),
    array('uid' => 3, 'first_name' => 'Super', 'last_name' => 'Man'),
  );

  $header = array(
    'first_name' => t('First Name'),
    'last_name' => t('Last Name'),
  );
  $options = array();
  foreach ($users as $user) {
    $options[$user['uid']] =array(
      'first_name' => $user['first_name'],
      'last_name' => $user['last_name'],
    );
  }
  $form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#empty' => t('No users found'),
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

I am hoping/guessing it something simple like setting something in the options array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this I understand how `#default_value` works now. It has to be an array.

```
$values = array();

$values[1] = TRUE;
$values[2] = FALSE;
$values[3] = TRUE;

$form['table'] = array(
    '#type' => 'tableselect',
    '#header' => $header,
    '#options' => $options,
    '#default_value' => $values,
    '#empty' => t('No campground to claim'),
  );
```